# How can I prevent drawing Z shapes, when making straight lines in photopea on mobile?

Tags: mobile, photopea

I know how to draw straight in photopea on mobile. The keyboard button let's me press the shift key, so multiple clicks draw a straight line between the points clicked.

However even if I disable the on-screen shift, then re-enable it, the third press then makes a second line.

[image: photo of a church with two lines connected by a third forming a z shape]

In this image the diagonal line is the ones I don't want to have made.

How can I prevent this, when drawing straight lines in photopea on mobile?

Comment: In Photoshop, one muse click, *then* press shift, click again, release shift. You can't depress shift *before* the click - only *after* the click. No idea if this matters in Photopea.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, I will give it a go and self answer if it helps :)

Comment: @Scott answered and credited you.

Comment: No need :) I'm just glad that sorted it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3270/scott) mentioned in his [comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159791/how-can-i-prevent-drawing-z-shapes-when-making-straight-lines-in-photopea-on-mo#comment241584_159791):

> In Photoshop, one [must] click, then press shift, click again, release shift. You can't depress shift before the click - only after the click. [...]

And that seems to do the trick in PhotoPea as well, even with the on-screen keyboard button.